# Gradle - How to execute a group of files as one thread in a task?

Tags: gradle

Actually I have a JavaExec task which processes files in a folder(say 2000 files). I want my task to create 10 threads, each thread should be processing 200 files, all these threads should run in parallel to one another so that I can reduce the overall build time. Please help me out fix the issue.

Also suggest if there is any other approach to do the same thing in a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think gradle wont allow to create multiple threads..may you can customize your java exec to create mutiple threads.